# KeepassXC update

Tags: homebrew, software-update, apple-silicon

A new release of [KeepassXC](https://keepassxc.org/download/) has been released and I want to update it on my MacOS M1.
However, when I try it:

```
% brew upgrade --cask keepassxc 
Error: Cask 'keepassxc' is not installed.
```

Probably because I haven't originally installed with brew?

How do I update it then?

I am afraid to substitute the app in Applications will delete the database.

Comment: Don't you have backups?  If not, fix that problem first.

Answer (score 2):

> Probably because I haven't originally installed with brew?

Exactly. You haven't installed KeePass XC with Homebrew, so they have no idea whether it's installed or not.

You can check which apps you've installed with Homebrew by running the following:

```sh
brew list --cask
```

> How do I update it then?

If you want to automate the process via Homebrew in the future, the easiest thing might be to manually uninstall the app and then run `brew install keepassxc`.

> I am afraid to substitute the app in Applications will delete the database.

The database is a separate kdbx file, completely unrelated to the app. Uninstalling the app might mean that any KeePass XC configurations/settings might be reverted, but the database will be fine.

Comment: `brew list` seems to list more than just what's installed by Homebrew. For me, the `list --cask` command shows "installed" apps that aren't actually installed (either by Homebrew or even manually) and thus can't be removed.